# Delphi OOP Interface, delegated method, why and when is which one called?

Tags: oop, delphi, interface

I am playing around with Interfaces.

```
unit uMain;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls;

type
  IOrcs = interface
  ['{89B86797-9F86-48B8-8D0B-01A78C2CA523}']
    function Enemies : string;
  end;
  IHumans = interface
  ['{D32C39A3-C654-4078-BD5A-0D3793530FB0}']
    function Allies : string;
  end;

  TOrc = class (TInterfacedObject, IOrcs)
    function Enemies : string;
  end;

  THuman = class (TInterfacedObject, IHumans)
    function Allies : string;
  end;

  TElves = class (TInterfacedObject, IHumans,IOrcs)
  private
    fOrc : IOrcs;
  public
    constructor Create;
    function Enemies : string;
    function Allies : string;

    property Orc : IOrcs read fOrc implements IOrcs;
  end;


  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    btnHumans: TButton;
    btnOrcs: TButton;
    ListBox1: TListBox;
    btnElves: TButton;
    procedure btnHumansClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure btnOrcsClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure btnElvesClick(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
    procedure Log ( str : string );
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

{ TOrc }

function TOrc.Enemies: string;
begin
  Result := 'Our Enemies Humans';
end;

{ THumans }

function THuman.Allies: string;
begin
  Result := 'Our Allies Elves';
end;

{ TForm1 }

procedure TForm1.btnElvesClick(Sender: TObject);
var Allied : IHumans;
    Horde : IOrcs;

    Test : TElves;
begin

  Allied := TElves.Create;

  Log('IHumans');

  Log(Allied.Allies);

  Log('IOrcs');

  Horde := Allied as IOrcs;

  Log(Horde.Enemies);

  Log('TElves.Create');

  Test := TElves.Create;

  Log(test.Allies);
  Log(test.Enemies);
end;

procedure TForm1.btnHumansClick(Sender: TObject);
var Allied : IHumans;
begin

  Allied := THuman.Create;

  Log(Allied.Allies);


end;

procedure TForm1.btnOrcsClick(Sender: TObject);
var Horde : IOrcs;
begin

  Horde := TOrc.Create;

  Log(Horde.Enemies);
end;

procedure TForm1.Log(str: string);
begin
  ListBox1.Items.Add(str);
end;

{ TElves }

function TElves.Allies: string;
begin
  Result:='Wood Elves';
end;

constructor TElves.Create;
begin
  fOrc := TOrc.Create;
end;

function TElves.Enemies: string;
begin
  Result:='Orcs and Dwarwes';
end;

end.
```

The question here is regarding `TElves`.

I have a function `Enemies()`, and I have a property `Orc` which implements `IOrcs`, so I guess that is why the `Enemies()` function is called from `IOrcs` instead of locally.

If I comment out the property, the local `Enemies()` function is called.

I obviously do not understand the use case of this. Maybe I am doing this completely wrong. But when using `IInterface` instead of `TClass`, is there a way to call the local function?

Comment: No. It will use `IOrcs` implementation because it is how you declared it. I am not sure what is the actual problem you want to solve, but I can tell that your class organization is completely wrong. `TElves = class (TInterfacedObject, IHumans,IOrcs)` say that ELVES are HUMAN and ELVES are ORCS. Neither is true. Elves are completely separate and they shouldn't implement neither `IHuman` nor `IOrcs` interface.

Comment: You want to have `IAssociations` (or whatever name you want to call it) interface that will have both `Allies` and `Enemies`  functions and all races would implement that interface, but for each race those functions would return different values.

Comment: sorry guys , obviously the naming in the example was not the best...

Comment: The original question still stands, if you already have local implementation, than what is the purpose of the field? The whole point of such field is to delegate some interface implementation to that field, so that you don't have to have those local functions declared and implemented.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar : obviously I've gotten confused here . It made no sense to have a Local Implementation if I am delegating it ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method is called from TOrcs because of the `implements IOrcs` in:

```
property Orc : IOrcs read fOrc implements IOrcs;
```

The implements directive allows you to delegate implementation of an interface to a property in the implementing class.

It mean that the implementation of `IOrcs` in your class will use `fOrc`

```
  TElves = class (TInterfacedObject, IHumans,IOrcs)
  private
    fOrc : IOrcs;
  public
    constructor Create;
    function Enemies : string;
    function Allies : string;

    property Orc : IOrcs read fOrc;
  end;
```

Comment: This also means that there is no way the Local function will every get called ? 
I guess I got confused in this entire thing .

Comment: if your remove the `implements` from the `Orc` property, the local function of `TElves.Enemies` will be called